# Refactoring Scala to use search functions as arguments results in Option[Any] issue

Tags: scala

So originally I had the following. It contains a lot of boiler-plate:

```
  private def getCollection(newState: Asset, currentState: Option[Asset]) =
    newState.assetGroup.flatMap(_.collection) match {
      case Some(collection) => Some(collection)
      case None => currentState match {
        case Some(state) => state.assetGroup.flatMap(_.collection)
        case None => None
      }
    }

  private def getChildSource(newState: Asset, currentState: Option[Asset]) =
    newState.content.flatMap(_.contract.flatMap(_.childSource)) match {
      case Some(childSource) => Some(childSource)
      case None => currentState match {
        case Some(state) => state.content.flatMap(_.contract.flatMap(_.childSource))
        case None => None
      }
    }

  private def getParentSource(newState: Asset, currentState: Option[Asset]) =
    newState.content.flatMap(_.contract.flatMap(_.parentSourceId)) match {
      case Some(childSource) => Some(childSource)
      case None => currentState match {
        case Some(state) => state.content.flatMap(_.contract.flatMap(_.parentSourceId))
        case None => None
      }
    }
```

So after some work I simplified it to the following:

```
  private def getCurrentField[A](newState: Asset, currentState: Option[Asset], searchFunction: Asset => Option[A]) : Option[A] =
    newState.content.flatMap(_.contract.flatMap(_.childSource)) orElse {
      currentState match {
        case Some(state) => searchFunction(state)
        case None => None
      }
    }

  val getCollection : Asset => Option[Collection] = (state : Asset) => state.assetGroup.flatMap(_.collection)
  val getChildSource : Asset => Option[String] = (state : Asset) => state.content.flatMap(_.contract.flatMap(_.childSource))
```

...but this gives me a compiler error:

```
    [warn] <filename_removed>.scala:68: a type was inferred to be `Any`; this may indicate a programming error.
[warn]       currentState match {
[warn]                    ^
[error] _:67: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Option[Any]
[error]  required: Option[A]
[error]     newState.content.flatMap(_.contract.flatMap(_.childSource)) orElse {
[error]                                                                 ^
[warn] one warning found
[error] one error found
```

If I remove the return type to `getCurrentField`, it compiles and the tests pass, but I still get that compiler warning: `a type was inferred to be Any`.

What's the best way to deal with type parameters in this situation?

Comment: When refactoring with scala, I recommend always starting by adding return type annotations onto the starting code.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `_.childSource` is of type `Option[Asset]`, and `searchFucntion` returns `Option[A]`. So, when both `_.contract` and `_.childSource` are both defined (`.flatMap` returns `Some`), you are returning `Option[Asset]`, and in the other case (`.orElse`) the returned type is `Option[A]`.

So, the resulting return type of your function has to be `Option[Any]`, because `Any` is the only common superclass of `Asset` and `A`, as far as the compiler can know.

Answer (score 0):

In my refactored version, I had replaced one of the search functions, but not the other. The following removes the warning, compiles and tests correctly:

```
  private def getCurrentField[A](newState: Asset, currentState: Option[Asset], searchFunction: Asset => Option[A]) : Option[A] =
searchFunction(newState) orElse {
  currentState map searchFunction getOrElse None
}
```